# timeline new comments count php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to solve next problem:

I need the most optomized solution for count new time comments in blogposts.

My own solution is:

create one more tbl, where save blogpost_id, lastview_num_comment what updated with every review of post, and count_num_comment what == blog_post.num_comments

example:

```
<?php 
function post($id){
   if($id && $id!=0){
      $sql = "SELECT `num_comments` FROM `blog_post` WHERE `id`=".quote_smart($id);
      $res=mysql_query($sql);
      $rw=mysql_fetch_array($res);
      $sql = "UPDATE `new_comments` SET last_view_numcom=".$rw['num_comments'];
      if(mysql_query($sql)){
         return 1;
      }else $this->error("database connect failed");
   }else redirect("");
}
?>
```

but with everyone adding comment i need to use update query what aren't the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is better solution if you need real time number. Otherwise you could update this every x minutes by cron.

However you can improve this code by reducing it to one mysql_query run:

`$sql = "UPDATE`new_comments`SET last_view_numcom = (SELECT`num_comments`FROM`blog_post`WHERE`id`=".quote_smart($id).")";`

Comment: but if i have over 1k users and over 5k posts, it's about 5k queries with every comment adding. Any ideas?

Comment: How much does it take to run this one update query and how much it takes if you would like to SELECT COUNT(*) this amount from comments table? I can't see why so simple update needs to be optimized.

Comment: If there is huge traffic in comment table maybe try using innoDb if you are using myIsam (myIsam locks whole table while read/write, innoDb locks single rows)